# apache: virtual hosts point to one host all the time

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Hi I have this problem with a new rackspace cloud server.

i have an apache where the ServerName is set to mydomain.com 
the DocumentRoot is /var/www/html

and I have a few virtual hosts too which I want to have in this server

I got a seperate file called hosts.conf in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ the content of it looks like this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80 

<Directory /var/domains>
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>     

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain-1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/domains/mydomain-1.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain-1.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain-1.com
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain-2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/domains/mydomain-2.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain-2.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain-2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

so the problem is when I add try to access the three websites,

mydomain.com, mydomain-1.com and mydomain-2.com, all of them returns the mydomain.com content.

any help is appreciated

thanks

Comment: If your OS is *debian* based, you could use *a2makesite* http://code.google.com/p/a2makesite/

Comment: the os is centos

Comment: Do you see any error? My VirtualHost entry is like `<VirtualHost *>` and I have `NameVirtualHost *` and `Listen 80` in my apache configuration files.

Comment: i dont see any error,

Comment: What's the output of `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -t -DDUMP_VHOSTS`?

Comment: @LinusKleen this is the output http://pastebin.com/PkL2JP3x

Comment: Then check the access logs for each domain. If not so configured, then do this. It should tell you whether or not a request *actually* reaches the vhost and more importantly what the HTTP response code is.

Comment: @LinusKleen perfect point. I could find the issue, thanks for your help

Comment: I'm glad that helped. Maybe you'd like to answer this question yourself then?

Comment: @LinusKleen yip I will do, but the solution is a bit stupid, I had the full path as for the log files of the server, you know /var/logs/blah.log and I changed this from to logs/blah.log and it worked. but looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try `NameVirtualHost` ing each specifically:

```
NameVirtualHost mydomain-1.com:80 
NameVirtualHost mydomain-2.com:80
```

and add the server name in the VirtualHost directive:

```
<VirtualHost mydomain-1.com:80>
```

Comment: that didnt work

Comment: @nivanka are you sure hosts.conf is being parsed?

Comment: yes it is being parsed